# re-balance hbase regions by table

Tags: hbase

The HBase version is 0.98. After restarting the HBase, all the regions are shuffled across the cluster nodes and they are not evenly distributed. So I use the command `balancer` to rebalance the table. But the regions are not balanced by the table. Please see the following figure. Is there a way to make all regions are balanced by table?

[image]

Answer (score 0):

I read an article about that but i could not find it now. Hbase assing regions by count to regions servers and as you see they are equal in each region server. but hbase does not have a table or load balancing feature when assigning regions so this leads heavy write/read tables in few regions and big and unused tables on other unused region servers.

if you google you can find a [jira task](https://issues.apache.org/jira/browse/HBASE-3373) in hbase project that they are tyring to fix this by adding table and load awareness to this process.

Comment: Also refer this link https://community.hortonworks.com/questions/65208/hbase-balancer-at-a-table-level.html